# Difference between eval execution of a command and assigning the result of the command execution to a variable

Tags: bash, eval

In the following script

```
#!/bin/sh

CMD="ls -al"

Z=`$CMD`

echo $Z

echo "-----"

eval $CMD
```

what is the practical difference of the invocation of `ls -al` via `$CMD` and eval and why in the second case the output is printed without newlines, while the direct `eval` output preserves newlines?

```
▶ ./test.sh
total 8 drwxr-xr-x 6 pkaramol staff 192 Dec 1 00:33 . drwx------@ 9 pkaramol staff 288 Dec 1 00:32 .. -rw-r--r-- 1 pkaramol staff 0 Dec 1 00:33 file1.txt -rw-r--r-- 1 pkaramol staff 0 Dec 1 00:33 file2.txt -rw-r--r-- 1 pkaramol staff 0 Dec 1 00:33 file3.txt -rwxr-xr-x 1 pkaramol staff 73 Dec 1 00:32 test.sh
-----
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  6 pkaramol  staff  192 Dec  1 00:33 .
drwx------@ 9 pkaramol  staff  288 Dec  1 00:32 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 pkaramol  staff    0 Dec  1 00:33 file1.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 pkaramol  staff    0 Dec  1 00:33 file2.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 pkaramol  staff    0 Dec  1 00:33 file3.txt
-rwxr-xr-x  1 pkaramol  staff   73 Dec  1 00:32 test.sh
```

Comment: Copy/paste your script into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues it tells you about. That will also answer some of your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you didn't quote `echo $Z` the word splitting removed the newlines.

Before the `echo` is executed, every character in `$IFS` (i.e. space, tab, and newline) creates a new argument. So `echo` does not see one long string but a lot of arguments (none of which contains a space, tab, or newline). These arguments are concatenated with one space in between.

So the solution is to use `echo "$Z"` so that the IFS characters are protected.